# How to put variable values in the other list of list using pandas/python

Tags: python, pandas, list

I have two variables :

```
date = 2018-10-25
```

In that all dates are stored

```
df =[['Euro', 0.8762059999999999], ['British Pound', 0.7755920000000001], ['Indian Rupee', 73.246211], ['Australian Dollar', 1.4093959999999999], ['Canadian Dollar', 1.308288], ['Singapore Dollar', 1.379124], ['Swiss Franc', 0.999036], ['Malaysian Ringgit', 4.1631849999999995], ['Japanese Yen', 112.293159], ['Chinese Yuan Renminbi', 6.944638]]
```

like that list of list are there.

I want Output:`[['Euro',2018-10-25, 0.8762059999999999],['British Pound', 2018-10-25, 0.7755920000000001],['Indian Rupee',2018-10-25, 73.246211],....]` like that for all element of the list with for loop using pandas/python.

And want to store that in Mysql Database So, how its query comes?

So please help guide me how should i do.
I tried this but not working :

```
 total = []
 for i in df:
         total = [df[0][0], date, df[0][1]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
date = '2018-10-25'
for i in df:
    i.insert(1,date)

In [1154]: df
Out[1154]: 
[['Euro', '2018-10-25', 0.8762059999999999],
 ['British Pound', '2018-10-25', 0.7755920000000001],
 ['Indian Rupee', '2018-10-25', 73.246211],
 ['Australian Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.4093959999999999],
 ['Canadian Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.308288],
 ['Singapore Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.379124],
 ['Swiss Franc', '2018-10-25', 0.999036],
 ['Malaysian Ringgit', '2018-10-25', 4.1631849999999995],
 ['Japanese Yen', '2018-10-25', 112.293159],
 ['Chinese Yuan Renminbi', '2018-10-25', 6.944638]]
```

Now, you can create a `dataframe` from above to insert into `Mysql`

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
frame.columns = ['Currency' ,'date', 'value']
frame.date = frame.date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
In [1156]: frame
Out[1156]: 
                       0           1           2
0                   Euro  2018-10-25    0.876206
1          British Pound  2018-10-25    0.775592
2           Indian Rupee  2018-10-25   73.246211
3      Australian Dollar  2018-10-25    1.409396
4        Canadian Dollar  2018-10-25    1.308288
5       Singapore Dollar  2018-10-25    1.379124
6            Swiss Franc  2018-10-25    0.999036
7      Malaysian Ringgit  2018-10-25    4.163185
8           Japanese Yen  2018-10-25  112.293159
9  Chinese Yuan Renminbi  2018-10-25    6.944638

from pandas.io import sql
import MySQLdb

frame.to_sql(con=con, name='table_name', if_exists='replace', flavor='mysql', index=False)
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: No sir still ::  ['Euro', datetime.date(2018, 10, 23), 0.8709], ['British Pound', datetime.date(2018, 10, 23), 0.770299],.........................that datetime.date coming...I am trying in pycharm

Comment: Check closely my `date` command. It has single-quotes.  `date = '2018-10-25'`

Comment: Sir, I am trying to make like-->  0  Euro  2018-10-25    0.876206  But my output is coming like---> 
0   Euro 1970-01-01 00:00:00.000000000  2018-10-23   So where i got wrong

Comment: And if i change the column name then " AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date' ". this come out...

Comment: df =[['Euro', '2018-10-25', 0.8762059999999999], ['British Pound', '2018-10-25', 0.7755920000000001],
 ['Indian Rupee', '2018-10-25', 73.246211],
 ['Australian Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.4093959999999999],
 ['Canadian Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.308288],
 ['Singapore Dollar', '2018-10-25', 1.3791]]                                      for i in df:
        i.append(date)

    print(df)
    #
    # frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
    # frame.columns = ['Cur', 'da', 'val']
    # frame.date = frame.date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
    # print(frame

Comment: Your `df` has date column already appended, and then your are running the `for` loop to insert date again. Are you doing it twice?

Comment: ohhh Sory sir , my mistake i send you wrong df = [['Euro', 0.8709], ['British Pound', 0.770299], ['Indian Rupee', 73.482175], ['Australian Dollar', 1.413724],......   date = DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-23', '2018-10-24', '2018-10-25', '2018-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D').           for i in df:
        i.append(date)

    print(df)

    frame = pd.DataFrame(df)
    frame.columns = ['Cur', 'da', 'val']
    frame.date = frame.date.apply(pd.to_datetime)
    print(frame)..................So after that my today sfirst comment error comes

Comment: Ok. So you have multiple values in your `date` list? Try like this : `date=['2018-10-23', '2018-10-24', '2018-10-25', '2018-10-26']`. Remove `DatetimeIndex` from it. And then run the `for` loop.

Comment: That datetime is comming in my date output :    today = datetime.today()
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-24', today)
#print(dates)

for i in dates:
    date = str(i.date())
    print(dates)

Comment: Try this:  `today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')` . Also, do this:
`dt = []`
`for i in dates:`
    `dt.append(i.strftime('%Y-%m-%d'))`

Comment: NOO sir Still ...code ---> today = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
dates = pd.date_range('2018-10-24', today)
print(dates)--> DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-24', '2018-10-25', '2018-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D', tz=None)

Comment: Check above comment. Basically, you need to convert your `dates` list that your are creating from `pd.date_range` to have string values. I did this in above comment. You will have `dt` as another list which is create from your `dates` list. This will have values `['2018-10-24', '2018-10-25', '2018-10-26']`

Comment: yes i already did that for i in dates:
    date = str(i.date())
    print(dates)--->DatetimeIndex(['2018-10-24', '2018-10-25', '2018-10-26'], dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='D', tz=None)

Comment: but after taht my 45min ago comment error is comming

Comment: Can you add me on gmail, we can chat there. My id: `mayankporwal011@gmail.com`

Comment: sure sir just a moment

Comment: send sir please check

Answer (score 0):

Super simple:

```
date = "2018-10-25"

df =[['Euro', 0.8762059999999999], ['British Pound', 0.7755920000000001], ['Indian Rupee', 73.246211], ['Australian Dollar', 1.4093959999999999], ['Canadian Dollar', 1.308288], ['Singapore Dollar', 1.379124], ['Swiss Franc', 0.999036], ['Malaysian Ringgit', 4.1631849999999995], ['Japanese Yen', 112.293159], ['Chinese Yuan Renminbi', 6.944638]]

// Loop through df, i being the position, and append the date to the end of each
// of those arrays under df, because df is a multi dimensional array.
for i in df:
   i.insert(1,date)

print(df)
```

Comment: yes its comming like that:  [['Euro', 0.8709, datetime.date(2018, 10, 23)], ['British Pound', 0.770299, datetime.date(2018, 10, 23)],......But squence is not correct as i shown. If i want to change sequence then what should i do......and its showing datetime.date , want to remove it.

Comment: @royal fixed :)